# htaccess: rewrite rule to allow some file types with parameters (optionally)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters

I've written a rule that redirect to my login page before checking or downloading a file:

```
Options -Indexes 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://mi.domain/*.$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*\.(pdf|ppt|pptx|htm|html|rar|zip|gz|tar|tif|txt)$ /security.php?file=$1 [NC]
```

If I visit https://mi.domain/omg.pdf works, but (to prevent cache browser) 
if I visit https://mi.domain/omg.pdf?v=1234 fails.

How to allow parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QSA` flag in your rule to allow original query string in your URL to be preserved:

```
Options -Indexes 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://mi.domain/*.$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*\.(pdf|ppt|pptx|htm|html|rar|zip|gz|tar|tif|txt)$ /security.php?file=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```